# Создание динамического окружения в Unity

Tags: unity3d

это не первый мой вопрос, на тему unity. Хочу реализовать идею динамического окружения, вроде того, что можно было увидеть в первый асасинах в анимусе. Интернеты предлагают создание системы частиц, но она получается привязана к камере и частицы меняют своё положение в зависимости от движения персонажа. Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы оно всё ещё было привязано к персонажу, во избежание высоких нагрузках, но её прорисовка данного окружения была независима от того, куда смотрит камера.